# How to redirect to the particular web page based on a url in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting

I have a website like test.com.

Now i want when i type `test.com/test1` then a particular page is open. the corresponding url of `test1` is saved into my database. like if i type `test.com/test1` then `test.com/test/mytest1.aspx` is open and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ASP.NET Routing.

1) ASP.NET routing enables you to use URLs that do not have to map to specific files in a Web site. Because the URL does not have to map to a file, you can use URLs that are descriptive of the user's action and therefore are more easily understood by users.

Refer:

[ASP.NET Routing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

[Using ASP.NET Routing in a Web Forms Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd329551%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Also, Check

2) [IIS 7 URL Rewrite Module](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite): The Microsoft URL Rewrite Module 2.0 for IIS 7 and above enables IIS administrators to create powerful customized rules to map request URLs to friendly URLs that are easier for users to remember and easier for search engines to find.

[Creating Rewrite Rules for the URL Rewrite Module](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module)

Comment: i did suggest you to provide an example based on OPs question. would be great.

Comment: @KPL can u please give me an example

Comment: Refer the links. I have included links having complete explanation on how tho use ASP.Net Routing & IIS 7 Url rewrite module